# React-Native horizontal FlatList

Tags: react-native

I have flat list that is returning a JSON feed with nested objects / arrays. All is working except horizontal listing, it still lists each item vertically. Does anyone know how I can list the returned images horizontally instead of vertically?

```
{isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
      <FlatList
        data={[data]}
        horizontal={true}
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem= {({ item, index }) => (
          <View>
          {item.items.map((v, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Pdp', {articleid: item.id})}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.imgyoutubeprev} source={{ uri: chkValue(v.snippet.thumbnails.high.url) }} />
                <Image style={styles.imgyoutubebtnoverlay} source={require('../assets/youtubebtn.png')} />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
          </View>
        )}
      />
    )}
```

Comment: `item.items.map` Is inside a `View` which will render contents vertically by default, so every item in `item.items` will be stacked vertically, not sure if that's what you want or not

Answer (score 1):

We would need to have a bit more information about the styles that you are using. If the items are rendered vertically instead of horizontal then this is likely caused by the element that surrounds the `FlatList`.

Make sure that the `View` or other component that contains the `FlatList` has the `flex: 1` style or at least takes up the full width. Otherwise the horizontal elements would still wrap and be rendered vertically.

**Bonus tip:** You might be able to remove the `View` child from the `TouchableOpacity` by moving the `styles.container` to the `TouchableOpacity` and then replacing the inner `View` with a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. The big difference was removing the view surrounding the item.items.map. I haven't had to force flex: 1 against the view, though I have forced flex 1 across the whole screen, so possibly thats helped as well. Thanks again all.

The code I used (taking on your code reduction, and is working as expected is;

```
return (
    <View>
    {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
      <FlatList
        data={[data]}
        horizontal={true}
        horizontal
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem= {({ item, index }) => (
          item.items.map((v, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Pdp', {articleid: item.id})}>
                <Image style={styles.imgyoutubeprev} source={{ uri: chkValue(v.snippet.thumbnails.high.url) }} />
                <Image style={styles.imgyoutubebtnoverlay} source={require('../assets/youtubebtn.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))
        )}
      />
    )}
  </View>
  );
};
```